# You must wait until January 22

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

“You must wait until January 22 before you can get or use your pass”. Is that means I have to wait on the 23:59 of January 22? Or 23:59 of January 21? Before they will give me my pass?

Comment: As soon as the 22nd shows up, you're ready. If it's that day, you have waited as they asked.

Comment: So meaning I will get my pass on the 22nd? Not the 23rd?

Comment: Im really mixed up, other said i have to wait after 22nd till i get my pass.

Comment: Or, if you have to pick it up manually, when the office opens? Or until they've sorted out any clerical errors? I'm afraid you must seek clarification on this from the issuing authority; the English is used in conflicting ways by different users.

Comment: Commonsense dictates that the date they mention is the day on which you can get your pass.

Answer (score -2):

It means that you have to wait on the **23:59 of January 21**. After that it's OK and you can use your pass without any problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But the question contains “You must wait until January 22 before you can **get** or use your pass”. The office might not open at midnight. The passes might be late arriving there. They may not arrive before evening. _This assumes that there is not a real problem, like a printer's strike._